# Updating UILabel.text is slow

Tags: ios, swift

Right now, my view controller is doing some very simple things:

1. Call a web service
2. Println a value
3. Set a UILabel's text value to that value

1 & 2 are pretty snappy.  The third step takes about 10 seconds to appear on screen in the simulator.

```
        switch currentTemp {
    case 80..<180:
        self.riskType.text = "Heat Index:"
        self.perceivedTemperatureValue.text = "\(currentHeatIndex)"
    case -100..<50:
        self.riskType.text = "Wind Chill:"
        self.perceivedTemperatureValue.text = "\(currentWindChill)"
    default:
        self.riskType.text = "Temperature:"
        println(currentTemp)
        self.perceivedTemperatureValue.text = "\(currentTemp)"
    }
```

Any idea why this is so slow?  Is there something else I need to do to make the change appear as soon as I println the value?

Comment: you do the updating in which thread?

Comment: Can you post more of your code? Where is the `switch` statement called from?

Comment: it might be a problem of doing update in background which is not slow in fact but you do not see results immediately

Comment: On the train, so no more code until the morning. However, if it helps, the switch statement is inside a protocol method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's not a whole lot to go on in the code you posted, but it sounds like you're doing your label updates directly in your web service callback, which usually runs on a background thread. **All UI work needs to be done on the main thread or you'll run in to problems like this.** If so, running that `switch` statement on the main thread using GCD's `dispatch_async` will fix your problem:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    switch currentTemp {
    case 80..<180:
        self.riskType.text = "Heat Index:"
        self.perceivedTemperatureValue.text = "\(currentHeatIndex)"
    case -100..<50:
        self.riskType.text = "Wind Chill:"
        self.perceivedTemperatureValue.text = "\(currentWindChill)"
    default:
        self.riskType.text = "Temperature:"
        println(currentTemp)
        self.perceivedTemperatureValue.text = "\(currentTemp)"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that a try first thing in the AM.